# Postgresql regex replace text field

Tags: regex, file, postgresql, text, replace

Hi guys I have question about regex, can you help me extract date from text like:

```
Start   20130918 14:35:00
```

I wan extract 20130918 only from text. 
I've tried something like this:

```
regexreplace(Start('\s+\w{5}\d{8}\s',''))
```

Comment: You say you want to extract the date, but yet you are replacing everything except the time with an empty string, what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I want extract only date from text, remove start and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following expression for matching the line:

```
Start\s+([0-9]{8})\s.*
```

and then a replacement string: `\1`.

**NOTE:** You might need to double escape each backslash if you are passing the expression as a string, so you might need to use:

```
Start\\s+([0-9]{8})\\s.*
```

**EDIT:** You can use the following statement:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Start 20130918 14:35:00','Start\s+([0-9]{8})\s.*','\1')
```

and here is an [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6d80e/186/0)

Comment: But when I do this, I get only output Start.

Comment: SELECT regexp_replace('Start   20130918 14:35:00','\w{5}\s+([0-9]{7})\s*.','')

Comment: and with this I get output time, it's a bit hard for me extract only date, everthing else removed.

Answer (score 4):

Better to use substring than regex_replace for this type of problem:

```
select substring('Start   20130918 14:35:00' from '[0-9]{8}')
```